# Go program panics when accessing the Thread Environment Block

Tags: windows, go, assembly

I'm developing on a Go library to access some internal Windows thread structures (Thread Environment Block) and this requires writing some assembly code. I've been trying to understand why this works on a Win32 C++ application but it doesn't on my Go library.

This snippet of Go assembly code accesses **fs:[0x18]** to return a pointer to the thread's associated **TEB**:

```
    // func ReadFsDword(offset uint32) (dword uint32)
    TEXT ·ReadFsDword(SB),$0-8
            MOVL offset+0(FP), AX
            // mov eax, dword ptr fs:[eax]
            BYTE $0x64; BYTE $0x8B; BYTE $0x00
            MOVL AX, ret+8(FP)
            RET
```

This is the equivalent MASM code, which compiles and runs just fine on MSVC:

```
void* readfsdword(unsigned offset_)
{
    unsigned dw;

    __asm {
        mov eax, offset_
        mov eax, fs:[eax]
        mov dw, eax
    }

    return (void*)dw;
}
```

The Go program panics when accessing the returned pointer to the TEB. Here's the message I get:

> panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer
>   dereference [signal 0xc0000005 code=0x0 addr=0x0 pc=0x498d5b]

The Go assembly code seems right to me, but I can't understand how and why the program panics. Any help is much appreciated!

Here's an example to reproduce the issue:

***intrinsics.s***

```
#include "textflag.h"
#include "funcdata.h"

// func ReadFsDword(offset uint32) (ret uint32)
TEXT ·ReadFsDword(SB),$0-8
        MOVL offset+0(FP), AX
        // mov eax, dword ptr fs:[eax]
        BYTE $0x64; BYTE $0x8B; BYTE $0x00
        MOVL AX, ret+8(FP)
        RET
```

***intrinsics.go***

```
package nt

func ReadFsDword(offset uint32) (ret uint32)
```

***test.go***

```
package main

import "nt"

func main() {
    GetProcAddress("LoadLibraryExW")
}

func GetProcAddress(proc string) unsafe.Pointer {
    teb := nt.NtGetTeb()
    fmt.Printf("%p", teb)

    // todo: implement
    return nil
}
```

Comment: You seem to load `BX` though.

Comment: My bad, it was a typo. The program still panics and yields the same behaviour. It looks like the TEB is unreadable.

Comment: Hmmm ... please double check what the code is that you are actually running.

Comment: Look at the edited question. The program panics as soon as the data pointed by fs:[0x18] is accessed.

Comment: Now v2 of the question uses `AX` but the machine code uses `ebx`. Try `64 8B 00`.

Comment: Is it `amd64`? Why your Go code uses `FP` (frame pointer) register when it's supposed to be using `FS`?

Comment: @kostix it's using `FP` to access argument and result. `FS` is in the machine code bytes (the prefix `64`).

Comment: @Jester I fixed the instruction with `64 8B 00`. The program now panics on this instruction. I wonder why fs:[18h] is inaccessible.

Comment: @NTAuthority Did the signal change?  Can you use a debugger to show us the content of all registers immediately before the crashing instruction or even better, provide us with a [mcve] so we can try out ourselves?

Comment: Absolutely, I'll add the example to the question. The signal is now `[signal 0xc0000005 code=0x0 addr=0x18 pc=0x47a244]`.

Comment: Note that according to [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Win32_Thread_Information_Block), the Thread Environment Block is accessed through GS, not FS in 64 bit mode.  Have you tried using GS and changing the offsets as indicated in the article?

Comment: @fuz You're absolutely right. I was working under the assumption the process runs in WoW64. I'll try to apply the suggested changes.

Comment: @fuz The problem was fixed. Indeed the gs segment selector is used in x64, with a different offset (0x30). The library now reads the correct values.

Comment: @NTAuthority Note that you can compile Go code as 32 bit code by defining the environment variable `GOARCH` to `386` while building.  If this is going to be a library, consider using appropriate build tags so it does the right thing for both architectures.

Comment: Does Go really use a stack-args calling convention in x86-64?  I don't get why a function arg would in memory relative to `RBP` at the start of a function.  (Or does FP expand to RSP if you build with optimization enabled?).   I don't really know Go, so maybe that's normal, but it still seem inefficient.

Comment: @Peter I don't know either. There probably is a way to use another calling convention (one that passes arguments via registers) but I haven't had time to dig into it.
I don't know if frame pointer omission is enabled by default and if `FP` is expanded to `SP`

Comment: You could try disassembling your binary with a real disassembler (into non-Go asm), or single-stepping it with a debugger, if you're curious.

Comment: Yes. I'll try loading it up in Immunity and get back with my findings.

Comment: @PeterCordes Yes, they do.  For simplicity.  The even pass the return value on the stack.

Comment: @fuz: Yuck, seems like a giant leap backwards in calling conventions.  Windows x64 is a pretty good tradeoff of simplicity vs. performance, if you don't want the complexity of x86-64 System V (especially for variadic functions), so IDK why they wouldn't use that.  Is Go very good at always inlining small functions or something, so this never matters much?

Comment: @PeterCordes They did this to make the compiler easier to write.  The ABI is not tied down and may be replaced by a more efficient one in the future.

Answer (score 5):

The problem was fixed. Apparently, Windows uses the `gs` register with an offset of 0x30 on x64 whereas `fs` and a 0x18 offset are used on x86/WoW64 mode. 
The solution is to use either `fs` or `gs` with the respective offsets depending on the value of `GOARCH`.

Comment: I find it interesting that it's exactly what [`u/aarzilli` warned about](https://www.reddit.com/r/golang/comments/9349cd/the_go_lowlevel_calling_convention_on_x8664/e3cc46d) in their Reddit comment to [this recently appeared document](http://science.raphael.poss.name/go-calling-convention-x86-64.html).